# App Store says Apple ID is disabled when updating apps

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I cannot update my apps, and I get a message saying that my Apple ID is disabled. However, I can still access my account and I have updated the settings and everything. But still I cannot update my apps, and the same message keeps popping up. How can I retrieve my Apple ID?

Answer (score 4):

Asking anyone but Apple why your account is disabled is generally fruitless.

Why not start with the troubleshooting guide:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204106

In the end, you'll want to contact Apple support if it's not you that's locking your account. If someone else is compromising or has compromised your account - you may have to patiently and over time prove to Apple you're the owner and regain control of it.